# Data leak while using StAX with OkHttp3 for parsing large SOAP responses

Tags: java, xml, stream, okhttp, stax

I'm trying to parse multiple large XML SOAP responses with StAX parser using the following code (tracker is a simple stack for keeping a track of the current XPATH):

```java
XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance()

while (true) {
    /*
     * <-- Request code -->
     */

    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    InputStream responseReader = response.body().byteStream();
    XMLEventReader eventReader = factory.createXMLEventReader(responseReader);

    while (eventReader.hasNext()) {
        XMLEvent event = eventReader.nextEvent();

        if (event.getEventType() == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT) {
            StartElement startElement = event.asStartElement();
            String elementBuffer = startElement.getName().getLocalPart();
            tracker.push(elementBuffer);
            String currentXPath = tracker.getXPath(); //Joins all elements in the stack with '/' as delimiter.

            if (eventReader.peek().getEventType() == XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS) {
                String data = eventReader.nextEvent().asCharacters().getData().replace('\n', ' ');

                if (currentXPath.equals("/ABC/DEF/GHI"))
                    // Do something
                if (currentXPath.equals("/JKL/MNO/PQR"))
                    // Do something

                /*
                 * Remaining operations
                 */
            }
        } else if (event.getEventType() == XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT) {
            tracker.pop();
        }
    }

    eventReader.close();
    responseReader.close();
    response.close();
}
```

**Problem:** The `data` String is getting truncated from the end and I'm randomly losing data.

Example:
`944aa679441c818d80bd8c7d7001229e` would randomly get truncated to `944aa679441c818d80bd8c7`
and
`100000000` will trim down to `10000`.

Can anyone please point out what's wrong with this code? I tried going through StAX & OkHttp documentation but found nothing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it:

```java
XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance()

while (true) {
    /*
     * <-- Request code -->
     */

    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    InputStream responseReader = response.body().byteStream();
    XMLEventReader eventReader = factory.createXMLEventReader(responseReader);

    while (eventReader.hasNext()) {
        XMLEvent event = eventReader.nextEvent();

        if (event.getEventType() == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT) {
            StartElement startElement = event.asStartElement();
            String elementBuffer = startElement.getName().getLocalPart();
            tracker.push(elementBuffer);
            String currentXPath = tracker.getXPath(); //Joins all elements in the stack with '/' as delimiter.

            if (eventReader.peek().getEventType() == XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS) {
                String data = "";
                
                while(eventReader.peek().getEventType() == XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS)
                    data += eventReader.nextEvent().asCharacters().getData().replace('\n', ' ');

                if (currentXPath.equals("/ABC/DEF/GHI"))
                    // Do something
                if (currentXPath.equals("/JKL/MNO/PQR"))
                    // Do something

                /*
                 * Remaining operations
                 */
            }
        } else if (event.getEventType() == XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT) {
            tracker.pop();
        }
    }

    eventReader.close();
    responseReader.close();
    response.close();
}
```